# Flutter how to remove image background

Tags: flutter, dart, image-processing, background-image, semantic-segmentation

I need to remove image background in flutter for all the three platform Android, IOS and web.

Ex : I have a image from gallery or camera and need to make background transparent.

how to do this without sdk or any third party api?
i am now using `https://www.remove.bg/` but its too expansive

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution but only for 'white' pixels. If for some reasons you don't want to remove white pixels, look at the second part.

1. Replace pixels

Firstly install `image` package on `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  image: ^3.0.8
```

And this following functions work:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

void makeTransparentBackground(File imageFile) {
  img.Image image = img.decodeImage(imageFile.readAsBytesSync())!;

  int white = img.getColor(255, 255, 255, 255);

  for (int y = 0; y < image.height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < image.width; x++) {
      if (image.getPixel(x, y) == white) {
        image.setPixelRgba(x, y, 0, 0, 0, 0);
      }
    }
  }
  File('imgNoBg.png')..writeAsBytesSync(img.encodePng(image));
}
```

2. Remove.bg Api

I thinks this is the best choice, you can take a look to the remove.bg's documentation right here: https://www.remove.bg/fr/api